# When Did Hashem Create Angels

Tags: creation, malach-angel

I always wondered when Hashem created angels because nowhere does it say in the Torah when Hashem created angels, only when Hashem created the world.

Comment: Rashi4Ever welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question! If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting. I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us.

Comment: see http://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/974948/jewish/When-were-the-angels-created.htm

Comment: In the beginning G-d created the heavens and the earth, what follows is a description of the components that were made in the earthly/physical realm. But what about the heavens? Maybe that part contains the creation of the heavenly court? I always find it interesting that when G-d made the firmament scripture doesn’t mentions what happened to the waters above, maybe those became part of heaven. Clearly the story is telling us just about our realm and not about the realm

Comment: Psalm 33:6 seems to talk about the creation of angels

Answer (score 10):

In the [Medrash Rabbah](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.1.3?with=all&lang=bi) there are two opinions. Rebbe Yochanan says that the angels were created on the second day, along with the firmament since we find in Tehillim a connection between the firmament and the Ruchos, which are taken to mean angels. Rebbe Chanina says they were created in the fifth day, and is alluded to in the words ועוף יעופף.

Answer (score 3):

We see according to Rav Hirsch and others in Vayeira that mal'achim are created for the appropriate task as they are needed. Consider the explanation as to why three mal'achim came to Avraham but two left to go to S'dom and save Lot. Thus, as each mala'ach is needed for its task, it comes into existence.

We also see that as a Jew does a mitzvah a "good" mal'ach is created and if otherwise, a prosecuting mal'ach comes into existence.

Thus, mal'achim are constantly being created.